# Loop through sheet 2 and copy specific values into specified columns on sheet 1

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I have a created the below loop to search for any value beginning with "R" plus a special character which is 10 characters long and paste these into the next blank cell on column 1 on another sheet.
I now need to develop this code to copy any values beginning with R on sheet2 and paste these into column 1 (A) on sheet1 and copy any value beginning with a numeric digit on sheet2 and paste these into column 4 (D) on sheet1

The "R" Value would be associated to the Numeric Value. For example, on sheet2 A1 could be R000000_01 and B1 (If a value is present) could be 12345 these two need to be copied into A3 and D3 as mentioned above

This is what I have created so far:

```
EnvRange = "A2:R999"

RowNo = 3
For Each C In Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(EnvRange)
If Len(C.Value) < 10 Then
GoTo NextCell
ElseIf Len(C.Value) < 11 Then
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowNo, 1).Value = C
RowNo = RowNo + 1
Else
Chars = InStr(1, C, "R")
Do While Chars < Len(C)
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowNo, 1).Value = Mid(C, Chars, 10)
Chars = InStr(Chars + 9, C, "R")
RowNo = RowNo + 1
If Chars = 0 Then GoTo NextCell

Loop
End If

NextCell: Next C
```

Your help in this matter would be very much appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Like` to check the format:

```
Sub Tester()

    Const ENV_RNG As String = "A2:R999"

    Dim c As Range, RowNo As Long, sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    RowNo = 3

    For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(EnvRange)
        If c.Value Like "R?????????" Then
            sht.Cells(RowNo, 1).Value = c.Value
            sht.Cells(RowNo, 4).Value = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
            RowNo = RowNo + 1
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: I have a very similar sub that i use to check dates and place values accordingly using the `For Each c In ...` method and it works flawlessly

Comment: Excellent! Thank you @Tim Williams! This worked like a charm!